# How to mirror any repository our own host?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, gitlab, version-control

My company sometimes work on client's git hosting solution (GitHub, GitLab, AzureDevops...), but we're worried that if they remove our access to said solution, we'd no longer have access to the code (except on the dev's machine, but that's not very convenient).

We're looking for a solution that allows us, for any repository we have access to, to maintain a copy of this repository (and all its branches) in our own gitlab server.

Is there any way to do that, that isn't dependent on the user ?
We sometimes hire external folks we have no control over, so it can't be something you install on user's pc.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a clone of a repository, you can do anything to it that you want. You can clone from one repo A and push everything to another repo B.

If they shut off access to repo A, you won't be able to see any updates to it, but you'll still have your repo B.

If you're looking for something that will regularly harvest everything from repo A and push it to repo B so it's always up-to-date, that's a software recommendation and outside the scope of StackOverflow.